Why `Function extends (() => void)` fails in TypeScript type definition
Why Function extends (() => void) fails in TypeScript type definition.
type C = (() => void) extends Function ? true : false; // type C = true
type D = Function extends (() => void) ? true : false; // type D = false

And in which situation should I use this global Function interface to define a function type?
I did not find any details in the official TypeScript handbook. Is there any instructions?

(fwiw: I did not downvote) Please [edit] this post to ask a single well-defined question. It seems you're asking why ()=>void is assignable to Function but not vice versa.  But then you're also asking "in which suituation...".  Please pick just one of those to ask. Otherwise this risks being closed as needing focus.

"in which situation should I use this global Function interface to define a function type?" basically never. The only exception I can think of is when you have a custom class that extends Function class MyFn extends Function, and even then the distinction is also captured at the term level. Note that Function is a global constructor in Javascript, not just an interface added by Typescript.

TLDR: Avoid Function whenever possible.

The TypeScript documentation states the following:
() => void is a Function Type Expression. It's the most straight forward and most accurate way to define a function type in TypeScript. Function Type Expressions allow you to define the exact shape of a function. This means you can define a specific list of parameters and a return type. Try to use this whenever possible. You'll get the best type safety and prevent bugs.
Function is a global inteface that is wider than () => void. Meaning your function expression is assignable to it but not the other way around. It describes properties present on all function values in JavaScript (e. g. bind, call, apply, toString, ...). I'd recommend to avoid using Function as it neither provides parameter type nor return type information - it always returns any.
Another risk is that things like classes are assignable to Function... You know what happens when trying to instantiate a class without the new keyword... 

Note that Function is a global constructor in Javascript, not just an interface in Typescript.... you can absolutely say const fn = new Function(...);

That is correct. However on type level, you compare the interface with () => void - not the JavaScript constructor ;)
